# Laravel: How to fix not detecting "username" input

Tags: mysql, laravel, localhost

I'm new to laravel and my code is working before but I changed "name" to "username" then if I click submit it says it doesn't have a default value.

```
class UserSignup extends Controller { 
    public function register(Request $request) {

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required', 'string','max:255', Rule::unique('users')],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')],
            'password' => 'required|min:8' 
        ]);

        $validatedData['password'] = bcrypt($validatedData['password']); 

        $user = User::create($validatedData);

return response()->json(['message' => 'User created successfully!', 'user' => $user]);
    } 
}
```

I tried changing the "name" to "username" as shown below

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required', 'string','max:255', Rule::unique('users')],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')],
            'password' => 'required|min:8' 
        ]);
```

After clicking submit there is an error that says it doesn't have a default value.

I just want the 'username' to be put in the database.

Comment: have you tried changing your table schema using [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations) ?

Comment: you need to change the database column from ``name`` to ``username`` and also in the ``User.php`` model file.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to [tag:localhost]? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might set `name` value to not nullable in your database (and migration). You have 2 options if you want to have `name` and `username` properties as well:

1. Set a default value for your `name` property (or set it to nullable) and add `username` property in your database using migration.
2. Create a `name` field in your registration form and in your request validation as well and now you can add it into your database record.

Hint: in your model file (`User.php`) you have to add every property you want to fill to the `$fillable` property:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'username', ...];
```

Comment: Here's the code in migration the email is okay but the username doesn't


Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('name')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();

Comment: I have updated my answer, I guess you haven't added the `username` property to the `$fillable` in your model file.

Answer (score -1):

I just put username in app.php and it worked

```
protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

check your model and database schema. seems you changed the controller but not updated the model fillable property.

`protected $fillable = ['username','....'];`

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it